# wsimport doesn't generate setters for collections

Tags: java, web-services, ant, jax-ws

I use the following Ant task to generate client-side code for a web service endpoint:

```
    <wsimport wsdl="target/classes/META-INF/wsdl/MyService.wsdl"
              sourcedestdir="target/wsimport"
              verbose="true"
              xnocompile="false"
              xendorsed="true"
              destdir="target/classes"
              keep="true"
              package="com.example.client.jaxws"
              wsdlLocation="/META-INF/wsdl/MyService.wsdl" />
```

This generates classes that the clients use to pass data to the web service, e.g.

```
class Foo {

  String name;
  List<String> bars;

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public List<String> getBars() {
    return bars;
  }
}
```

Notice that for the `bars` property the generated class does not include a setter, so the client would have to access it via:

```
someFoo.getBars().add("val");
```

However the absence of a setter means this class won't work with various tools that rely on the JavaBeans convention (e.g. Dozer), so I would like to force wsimport to generate the setters. I found a [thread](http://markmail.org/message/yzagyxyoo5tho4ed#query%3awsimport%20collection%20setter+page:1+mid%3azl73nkbsiz7ohrtq+state%3aresults) that indicates you can force setter generation by adding the following to the Ant task

```
<xjcarg value="-Xcollection-setter-injector"/>
```

However, this thread is quite old, and the above doesn't seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include a `jaxb xjc` extension library in your build classpath and use the `-Xsetters` xjcArg. This will cause your generated stubs to have setters for your `List` objects.

**For Maven users with the `jaxws-maven-plugin`, it looks like this:**

```
      <!-- generates webservice client stubs using wsimport -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxws-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <wsdlDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/${resources-folder}/wsdl/v1</wsdlDirectory>
                        <wsdlFile>${wsdlFileName}</wsdlFile>
                        <bindingFiles>
                            <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/jaxb-bindings.xml</bindingFile>
                        </bindingFiles>
                        <vmArgs>
                            <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg> <!-- necessary for JDK 8 -->
                        </vmArgs>
                        <xjcArgs>
                            <xjcArg>-Xsetters</xjcArg>
                        </xjcArgs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- put xjc-plugins on the jaxws-maven-plugin's classpath -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                    <version>0.9.5</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

**And for Maven users with the `cxf-codegen-plugin` it looks like this:**

```
        <!-- generates webservice client stubs using CXF framework-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>${adapter.api.wsdlFileName}</wsdl>
                                <bindingFiles>
                                    <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/jaxb-bindings.xml</bindingFile>
                                </bindingFiles>
                                <extraargs>
                                    <extraarg>-xjc-Xsetters</extraarg><!-- needed so that setters for lists are generated -->
                                </extraargs>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- plugin needed to customize cxf genrated classes -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                    <version>0.9.4</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

that functionality is provided by a plugin, the "jaxb2 commons collection setter injector" plugin.  did you include that jar on your xjc classpath?

Comment: I presume you mean an Ant plugin?

Comment: @Don - no, i mean a jaxb plugin